# Какие есть средства для разделения среды разработки и продакшена?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

У меня есть сервер с Ubuntu 16.04, на котором, я планирую, будет крутиться мой сайт. И то, что сейчас лежит на этом сервере(Gulp, Babel, PHP-движок, etc) - это продакшен-версия. А если я захочу запилить в будущем какой-то новый функционал? Не закрывать же мне сайт плашкой "ведутся работы, до свидания", пока я буду что-то новое пилить. Было бы круто, если бы на этом же сервере в отдельной папке на поддомене `developer.` можно было иметь дубль моего сайта, где я буду пилить обновы, тестировать какие-то фичи, а потом по кнопке закину все изменённые файлы в папку, где лежит продакшн-версия. Существует ли такая штука?

Comment: Самое простое - завести еще одну папку и домен (поддомен) и выкладывать туда дев версию сайта. Когда разработка и обновления закончены - выкатывать все на продакшен.

Comment: никогда, вообще никогда не располагай разрабатываемую версию и боевую на одном и том же сервере..должен быть отдельный сервер под разработку и под продакшн

Comment: Ваш сайт должен быть спроектирован так, чтобы можно было запускать неограниченное количество полностью независимых копий на неограниченном количестве серверов. Выностие все зависимые от сервера значения в отдельный файл-конфиг (домен, логин-пароль от БД, пути к временным каталогам, ключи для шифрования и т.п.) и запускайте копию сайта на отдельном тестовом сервере, отредактировав конфиг под этот самый тестовый сервер. Этим тестовым сервером может быть ваш обычный домашний компьютер.

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, было бы круто иметь development.yourcoolmegasite.com, закрытый хотя бы [basic-аутентификацией](https://www.google.ru/search?q=htaccess%20basic%20auth) (в идеале - с ограничением доступа по ip, но если нет "домашнего" белого ip - то можно ограничит доступ городом/страной... а можно и не ограничивать, НеуловимыйДжо-Секьюрити еще никто не отменял).

Как это сделать? Ну либо [руками](https://www.google.ru/search?q=apache%20site%20config), либо поставьте какой-нибудь IPS-Manager, Plesk или любую другую админ-панельку, и делайте это мышкой (а если вы на виртуальном хостинге - то только мышкой, в собственной панели хостера).

Еще было бы круто оформить код в отдельные [git](https://www.google.ru/search?q=git%20%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B)-репозитории, тогда можно использовать гит еще и как инструмент деплоймента (тобишь, переноса новых фишек на боевой сайт), и как "типа-антивирус" для отслеживания целостности кода на боевом сайте, и быстрого удаления вредоносов путем отката назад "сделайте мне как было". Конфиги только в [.gitignore](https://www.google.ru/search?q=.gitignore) пропишите, чтобы разные сайты продолжали смотреть в разные базы после деплоя.

Держать ли девелоперскую версию там же, где боевую? По феншую - конечно нет. На практике (с учетом неуловимости пресловутого Джо) - до некоторой степени пофигу, хоть баре-репозитарий держите там же (хотя, это уже бОльшее раздолбайство, равно как и держать их на облачных гит-хабах-и-компания... но, с другой стороны, это также зависит от Джо).

Ну только бэкапы делайте регулярно... и лучше, конечно, держите их где-то вовне... ну или опять же, спросите Джо, ему виднее...

UPD хотя не, про бэкапы погорячился... их в любом случае (хотя бы иногда) сливайте вовне... вредонос может сожрать сайт даже если он трижды-Джо :)

Answer (score 0):

Прочитав Ваш вопрос - понял одно, Вы уже сами на него ответили. Что Вам мешает сделать Вашу задумку реальностью? Правильно, ничего но - нужно время, а время это деньги... Мой совет создайте ядро проекта к примеру версия 1, и на поддомене расширяйте функционал с обновлением, при клике обновить основной домен обновляется и все...